# Turning navbar from an inline list to a block-type list for mobile version of a website - missing bullets

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to build a mobile-friendly version of a website and to this end I need to turn a navbar from an display:inline -style list to a bulleted list. For a minimal (not quite) working example here are the html and css-files:

```css
ul li {
  display: inline;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul li {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: circle; /* Not doing what I want. */
  }
  ul {
    list-style-type: circle; /* Not doing what I want either. */
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

This works otherwise as intended, but the mobile version is missing the bullets from in front of the list elements despite my attempts to force them in with the `list-style-type: circle` commands in the css. I know I can manually add a little circle in front of each list element, but this feels more like a shoddy work-around than a proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list-style-*` properties are being applied to `list-item` only.
When you set `li {display: inline}` you disabled the default appearance of `li`.

Use `display:list-item` to get it back.

Run the snippet below and resize the window:

```css
li {
  display: inline;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  li {
    display: list-item;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```